# No wifi on Ubuntu 20.04 Lenovo T14 Gen2

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04

After a fresh install of a Dual boot, i don't have wifi on the network settings.
I tried this https://dev.to/thexdev/ubuntu-20-04-fix-wifi-not-working-on-lenovo-ideapad-330-374j without success.

```
bastio@bastio-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2i:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 13d3:5406 IMC Networks Integrated Camera
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 06cb:00bd Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 116: ID 8087:0032 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

bastio@bastio-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2i:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2725] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0020]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0a:00.0 SD Host controller [0805]: Genesys Logic, Inc GL9750 SD Host Controller [17a0:9750] (rev 01)
bastio@bastio-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2i:~$ lsmod | grep cfg80211
cfg80211              778240  1 iwlwifi

bastio@bastio-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2i:~$ rfkill list all
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: tpacpi_wwan_sw: Wireless WAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
870: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
bastio@bastio-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2i:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: was this working on a previous version of Ubuntu?

Comment: It is the first time I try with this computer

Comment: Hum, i did not go further as I had the exact same problem on 21.04...

Comment: other people are reporting success on 21.04 ... it might be worth another go, with a fresh download? otherwise, "arch linux" might be your way to go for now?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to no support for the AX210 wifi card in Ubuntu.  When Lenovo was testing this laptop with, they used a [specific oem kernel](https://ubuntu.com/certified/202104-28912).

The solution is to install and then use this kernel on your computer instead of the one that comes with Ubuntu.

Kernel Version: 5.10.0-1022-oem